# Need to just show one line per agent name (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

New to this forum so go easy, I've become lost here and just want to show one line per name i.e. Joe Blogs....can anyone see where im going wrong as there is multiple lines per name currently.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = '2016-05-31 00:00:01', @EndDate = '2016-05-31 23:00:00'

SELECT      CONVERT(Varchar, AgentSession.SessionStart, 103) AS Date, 
            Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname AS AgentName, 
            ProductivitySummary.SessionStartTime As FirstLogin,
            ProductivitySummary.SessionEndTime As LastLogin,
            ProductivitySummary.PLogOnTime,
            (AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) As LogOnTime,
            (AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime) As TalkTime, 
            (AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime) As WaitTime,
            (AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime) As WrapTime, 
            AgentSession.BreakTime,
            AgentSession.MealTime,
            AgentSession.MeetingTime,
            AgentSession.OtherTime
FROM        Agent INNER JOIN
                      AgentSession ON Agent.AgentID = AgentSession.AgentID
            INNER JOIN(
SELECT      CONVERT(Varchar, AgentSession.SessionStart, 103) AS Date, 
            Agent.AgentID,
            Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname AS AgentName,
            MIN(AgentSession.SessionStart) SessionStart, 
            MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8)) AS SessionStartTime,
            MAX(AgentSession.SessionEnd) SessionEnd, 
            MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionEnd, 8)) AS SessionEndTime,
            CASE WHEN SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) > DATEDIFF(ss, (MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8))), (MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionEnd, 8)))) THEN SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) ELSE DATEDIFF(ss, (MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8))), (MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionEnd, 8)))) END AS PLogOnTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) As LogOnTime,
            COUNT(AgentSession.AgentID) Logouts,
            SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime) As TalkTime, 
            SUM(AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime) As WaitTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime) As WrapTime, 
            SUM(AgentSession.BreakTime) As BreakTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.MealTime) As MealTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.MeetingTime) As MeetingTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.OtherTime) As OtherTime
FROM        Agent INNER JOIN
                      AgentSession ON Agent.AgentID = AgentSession.AgentID
WHERE       (AgentSession.SessionStart Between @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (Agent.Lastname Not Like '%(DND)')
GROUP BY    CONVERT(Varchar, AgentSession.SessionStart, 103), Agent.AgentID, Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname
)ProductivitySummary
ON CONVERT(Varchar, AgentSession.SessionStart, 103) = ProductivitySummary.Date AND AgentSession.AgentID = ProductivitySummary.AgentID

WHERE       (AgentSession.SessionStart Between @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (Agent.Lastname Not Like '%(DND)')
ORDER BY    Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname ASC, CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this.. I just removed "AgentSession.SessionStart" from group by clause.. It seems there can be multiple session for Agent and you need Min of that, so that's should not be in Group By ... Rest you can try with this..  and let me  know if still getting multiple

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = '2016-05-31 00:00:01', @EndDate = '2016-05-31 23:00:00'

SELECT      CONVERT(Varchar, AgentSession.SessionStart, 103) AS Date, 
            Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname AS AgentName, 
            ProductivitySummary.SessionStartTime As FirstLogin,
            ProductivitySummary.SessionEndTime As LastLogin,
            ProductivitySummary.PLogOnTime,
            (AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) As LogOnTime,
            (AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime) As TalkTime, 
            (AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime) As WaitTime,
            (AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime) As WrapTime, 
            AgentSession.BreakTime,
            AgentSession.MealTime,
            AgentSession.MeetingTime,
            AgentSession.OtherTime
FROM        Agent INNER JOIN
                      AgentSession ON Agent.AgentID = AgentSession.AgentID
            INNER JOIN(
SELECT      CONVERT(Varchar, MIN(AgentSession.SessionStart), 103) AS Date, 
            Agent.AgentID,
            Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname AS AgentName,
            MIN(AgentSession.SessionStart) SessionStart, 
            MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8)) AS SessionStartTime,
            MAX(AgentSession.SessionEnd) SessionEnd, 
            MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionEnd, 8)) AS SessionEndTime,
            CASE WHEN SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) > DATEDIFF(ss, (MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8))), (MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionEnd, 8)))) THEN SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) ELSE DATEDIFF(ss, (MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8))), (MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionEnd, 8)))) END AS PLogOnTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime + AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime + AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime + AgentSession.BreakTime + AgentSession.MealTime + AgentSession.MeetingTime + AgentSession.OtherTime) As LogOnTime,
            COUNT(AgentSession.AgentID) Logouts,
            SUM(AgentSession.TalkTime + AgentSession.HoldTime) As TalkTime, 
            SUM(AgentSession.WaitTime + AgentSession.PreviewTime) As WaitTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.WrapTime + AgentSession.DeadTime) As WrapTime, 
            SUM(AgentSession.BreakTime) As BreakTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.MealTime) As MealTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.MeetingTime) As MeetingTime,
            SUM(AgentSession.OtherTime) As OtherTime
FROM        Agent INNER JOIN
                      AgentSession ON Agent.AgentID = AgentSession.AgentID
WHERE       (AgentSession.SessionStart Between @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (Agent.Lastname Not Like '%(DND)')
GROUP BY     Agent.AgentID, Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname
)ProductivitySummary
ON CONVERT(Varchar, AgentSession.SessionStart, 103) = ProductivitySummary.Date AND AgentSession.AgentID = ProductivitySummary.AgentID

WHERE       (AgentSession.SessionStart Between @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (Agent.Lastname Not Like '%(DND)')
ORDER BY    Agent.Firstname + ' ' + Agent.Lastname ASC, CONVERT(CHAR(8), AgentSession.SessionStart, 8)
```

Comment: yes I'm still getting them. I have managed though to resolve the issue with a grouping in SSDT.